# Filenet - Copy value from a workitem to document Property

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine, filenet-process-engine, filenet-cpe

I am new to Filenet BPM and I am trying to set a value from a workitem to document Property. Here is my requirement -

I have a Workflow with a document attached which should go to approval process, If it is approved then I have to set a property name 'status' in document property to 'Approved' and if it is rejected then I have to set it as 'rejected'. At first I thought it should be easy but I do not find any way to achieve this. Please help.

Comment: `At first I thought it should be easy but I do not find any way to achieve this.` <- What did you find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have the document as an attachment, use the default, out of the box CE_Operations queue to update the property. See the screenshot for a small sample.

[image: Process Designer]

Dependant on the outcome of the activity, you call the an operation and use the 'setStringProperty' operation. As attributes it takes the attached document, the property to update and the value to set.